# Как перекодировать данные из базы при выводе

Tags: php

У меня в php базе данных,хранится информация в таком виде:

`&lt;meta name=&quot;yandex-verification&quot; content=&quot;f7891bc8ba2a30be&quot; /&gt;`

Вывожу на сайт:

```
$Head_ID = $string['head'];
'.$Head_ID.'</head>
```

В коде сайта отображается так же, как и в базе

`&lt;meta name=&quot;yandex-verification&quot; content=&quot;f7891bc8ba2a30be&quot; /&gt;`

Как вернуть нормальный вид

`<meta name="yandex-verification" content="f7891bc8ba2a30be" />`?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`htmlspecialchars_decode($string)` 
Документация: [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

Comment: ya.ymer, спасибо!